# How to store a triggering action and events and call them when needed using python in qgis

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins, qgis-2

Can anyone explain in detail how to store the triggering action or an event that take place in the mapcanvas in a variable and call the same when needed in python?

Say for example,say i have pushbutton named 'areapushbutton' and if a user click that button in gui, it should store that action in a variable called mapselection and now plugin would call the select feature by freehand tool inside qgis and user should be able to select some features in mapcanvas  such that it it should also store this event in a variable selectionevent which i could later use like,

```
if action = mapselection and event = selectionevent:
    call this method()
```

What i needed is i want to know **how triggering action as well as the event should be defined or initialised and stored in a variable?

How to call select feature by freehand tool using python?

afterwhich it should automatically navigates the user to mapcanvas and allow to select And where those should added in our main py file?**

I dont have any idea of how to accomplish this.

Comment: So you want to active the freehand map tool to handle the selection and listen for when you have a new selection?

Comment: Yeah Nathan exactly and also to initailise or define the triggering action of a button in a variable and where should these both added in our main py file.

Comment: As per the [Tour] there should be only one question asked per question.